# Declare array PHP

Tags: php

I have a small issue, Did I wrong in declare array in method ?

```
function parseJsonString($string, &$table = []) {
....
}
```

The error result is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in D:\AppServ\www\test\parser.php on line 10"

Comment: This only works in php 5.4

Answer (score 2):

In PHP an empty array literal is `array()` not `[]`.

As mentioned in comments below `[]` is valid in PHP 5.4 and later.

Comment: True for most of PHP's lifetime, but `[]` *is* valid since PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

In php you should declare it as :

```
function parseJsonString($string, &$table = array()) {
 ....
}
```

see this http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

You can use your syntax only if your php version is >= 5.4